# What was the diameter of the (observable?) universe at the end of inflation?

Tags: cosmological-inflation

One reference says that during inflation, the universe expanded by a factor of 10**26. But I could find no reference to what the diameter was at the beginning. (Perhaps not surprisingly.) Is there an accepted value of the diameter of the universe at the end of inflation?

Comment: Question answered here.   http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32917/size-of-universe-after-inflation.  10^26 expansion (linear, not volume, volume is 10^78) mentioned here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflationary_epoch

Comment: It may seem strange that the observable universe expanding to about the size of a grain of sand (maybe) and that was the "end" of the inflationary Epoch.   I thought I'd throw that out there for weirdness.